# Проблема с google maps

Tags: google-maps-api

Есть 2 функции инициализации, но получается что работает та которая первее вызывается.

```
function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.2946862,28.6588384),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/images/map-marker1.png', new google.maps.Size(24, 35), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(12, 35)); //изображение маркера


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.5619059,27.7258658),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            }); 
    }



    function initialize_map() {
            var mapOptions = {
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoom: 5,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.8252589,16.0988428),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("home-map"), mapOptions);

            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/assets/images/map/map-marker1.png', new google.maps.Size(24, 35), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(12, 35)); //изображение маркера


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.078266, 10.034077),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(55.623705, 9.992593),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.183368, 5.508431),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.609833, 6.119563),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.506650, 4.686235),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.078732, 12.479782),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.789932, 24.997041),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.603790, 14.163416),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.715384, 15.082052),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.000690, 19.683416),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(48.696158, 19.309982),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            }); 
    }

    initialize_map();
    initialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код полностью рабочий вот пример: 
HTML:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:200px; width: 400px;"></div>
<div id="home-map" style="height:200px; width: 400px;"></div>
```

JS:

```
function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.2946862,28.6588384),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/images/map-marker1.png', new google.maps.Size(24, 35), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(12, 35)); //изображение маркера


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.5619059,27.7258658),
            map: map,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        }); 
}



function initialize_map() {
        var mapOptions = {
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.8252589,16.0988428),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("home-map"), mapOptions);

        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/assets/images/map/map-marker1.png', new google.maps.Size(24, 35), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(12, 35)); //изображение маркера


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.078266, 10.034077),
            map: map,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(55.623705, 9.992593),
            map: map,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.183368, 5.508431),
            map: map,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.609833, 6.119563),
            map: map,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.506650, 4.686235),
            map: map,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.078732, 12.479782),
            map: map,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.789932, 24.997041),
            map: map,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.603790, 14.163416),
            map: map,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.715384, 15.082052),
            map: map,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.000690, 19.683416),
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(48.696158, 19.309982),
            map: map,
            title: 'ClickCredit'
        }); 
}

    initialize_map();
    initialize();
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример:
https://jsfiddle.net/gsq475ra/

Две карты загружаются отлично изображения маркеров заменено на стандартные для наглядности

Comment: Странно почему у меня один вызов функции перекрывает другую

Comment: Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Comment: Я же прикрепил ссылку на рабочий пример в вашим кодом может вы ошиблись с id в html? Добавьте ваш ключ API google maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Я же говорю если убираю вызов одной из функций работает другая карта.

Comment: У вас две функции которые отрисовывают две разных карты если убрать вызов одной из функций то отрисуется только одна карта. Не понимаю вашего вопроса

Comment: У меня получается что отрисовывается карта первой вызванной функции,то есть второй идущий вызов за ней уже не работет

Comment: А в консоли ошибки есть? У меня как и в примере все работает. Какой код в HTML?

Comment: Ошибок нет,Id правильные

Comment: Разобрался,пришлось на каждой странице отдельно инициализацию прописать и там же вызвать